# iOS- how to make a UIImage look pixellated instead of fuzzy

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, uiimage

I'm not even sure how to phrase this question... but basically I have a small image, and I want to stretch it to cover the screen.  Because of the enlargement, the image is fuzzy, and I would prefer it to look blocky, so I can see the individual pixels as squares.  Is there any simple way to achieve this effect?

Comment: You might want to fish through the Core Image API documentation. There might be an effect in their that has the appearance you're looking for.

Comment: You want `aliasing` or `best neighbour`, Search the documentation to find anything related to those.

Comment: CIPixellate in CoreImage API. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Draw the image as the content of a layer and then enlarge it by enlarging the layer (give it a scale transform, or even better, use the `contentsRect` property to make the small image area fill the layer). The layer is backed only by the original bitmap, so you'll now be seeing the bits of the bitmap. IIRC it's even blockier if you use `shouldRasterize`.